# I need to gets articles for all days of each month in the previous 12 months, but My months & years are all wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a data from wiki &  I calculated months and years(2019, 2018) to see top articles. (all days of each month in the previous 12 months). The problem is it showing me the wrong months???

```
def get_current_year_month():

    all_data_list = []
    current_date = datetime.now()
    current_month = current_date.month
    current_year = str(current_date.year)
    current_year = current_year[-1:]

    for month in range(current_month, current_month + 12):
        if month > 12:
            year = current_year
            month = current_month - 12
        else:
            year = int(current_year) - 1
        if month < 10:
            month = "0" + str(current_month)

        data = f"https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/201{year}/{month}/all-days"
        all_data_list.append(data)
        print(data)
    return all_data_list
```

Comment: show what months you get and explain what wrong with them. Text `"it showing me the wrong months"` is useless.

Comment: By selecting the last digit of the year (`current_year[-1:]`), you are looking for a Y2K-style error. Why not just keep the year as an int?

Comment: you can use `print()` to see what you have in variables and how they change. THis way you can find where problem is.

Comment: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-days
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-days
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-days
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-days
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-days
https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/2018/04/all-da

Comment: Unexpected error.
Error: 'items'
File:  C:/Users/dropr/OneDrive/Harper college/Spring 2019_18weeks/CIS-206old/assign_11.py
Line:  67
Unexpected error.
Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
File:  C:/Users/dropr/OneDrive/Harper college/Spring 2019_18weeks/CIS-206old/assign_11.py
Line:  98

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in the line `month = "0" + str(current_month)`. Must be `month = "0" + str(month)`. Same with `month = current_month - 12`.

Complete corrected code:

```
def get_current_year_month():
    current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    current_month = current_date.month
    all_data_list = []
    for month in range(current_month, current_month + 12):
        year = current_date.year - (month <= 12)
        month = "{:02d}".format((month - 1) % 12 + 1)
        data = f"https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/top/en.wikisource/all-access/{year}/{month}/all-days"
        all_data_list.append(data)
    return all_data_list
```

Comment: you found it faster than me :)

Comment: The code generates the right months and years. You never asked about any articles.

Comment: You are right, I fixed my months and year.  Thanks for helping me out. For displaying articles: I found out that, my counter was 100 instead of 1000. That's why I could not display all 1000 top views articles. Thank you so much.